# How to select specific column from self reference model in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am developing documentation like system with a hierarchy data model.
This is my Table with self referencing relation-ship.

[image]

In table `[ParentId]`is the Foreign Key References `[Id]`.

This is my C# Model class for above table.

```
public class MNBCHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string HeadingNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public int PreviousHistoryID { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual MNBCHeader Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MNBCHeader> Children { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullTitle
    {
        get { return HeadingNumber + " " + Title; }
    }
    
}
```

Related child data will set to `public virtual ICollection<MNBCHeader> Children { get; set; }` with the Icollection type of current class MNBCHeader.

In order to load "table of content menu", I don't want to fetch "Content" Column. So, I fetch the data from top `Level` with below `linq` query.

```
var data = context.MNBCHeaders.Include(m => m.Children).Where(m => m.Level == 1)
            .Select(m => new
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                ParentId = m.ParentId,
                Level = m.Level,
                Title = m.Title,
                HeadingNumber = m.HeadingNumber,
                Children = m.Children
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is even if I didn't select 'Content' column in the query, I am getting the "Content" data inside the "Children" object type of `ICollection<MNBCHeader>`. How do I skip that "Content" data Inside nested collection `public ICollection<MNBCHeader> Children` of above model "MNBCHeader"?

This is current result which is having data in `Content` field.

[image]

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. ORMs are meant to map Objects to Relational data, not generate complex queries. In SQL you'd need to write [a recursive CTE](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) to retrieve hierarchical data from a self-referencing model, or use [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)  fields to both simplify and speed up queries. You can't do either with an ORM

Comment: In EF Core you could use `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated` to write a starting query in SQL and add LINQ operators to it. You could create stored procedures or functions that contain the recursive queries and map to them, or use `FromSql...`.

Comment: Try Children = m.Children.Select(x=>  new {x.id, .....}); if i am understanding you correctly that is what you need

Comment: No Clear your question, want you get content child ? or  if you know write SQL Query, update question then add this your query